# When creating a table in PostgreSQL, the table is created, but the columns aren't

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

When I run the following statement, the table is created, but there are no
columns:

```
CREATE TABLE "mod_1237" ("Collecteddepth" float8 NOT NULL, "Collectedtime"
float8 NOT NULL, "CollectedData" Varchar(45) NOT NULL, "Collectedpass"
float8 NOT NULL, "Collectedmodtime" float8 NOT NULL) WITH (OIDS = FALSE);
```

I know I'm not creating a primary key, but that shouldn't prevent the columns from being generated. When I run this code it also doesn't generate any errors so everything looks fine until I try to write to the table. Any ideas as to why this wouldn't work or how to make a table with the given columns?

I'm using PostgreSQL version 9.1.4 on Windows Server Standard SP2

Comment: -1 Cross posted to PostgreSQL mailing list here http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/E1TYJq5-00038e-4s@wrigleys.postgresql.org , didn't show the actual INSERT statement or error message.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered by Hubert ("Depesz") on the PostgreSQL mailing list, [where the question was cross-posted](http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/E1TYJq5-00038e-4s@wrigleys.postgresql.org). For the reference of anyone reading it here, [here is the answer](http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/20121113231947.GA7849@depesz.com). Since it hasn't been added to the archives yet that link will 404 for a little while, so I'll reproduce Herbert's answer below:

---

> most likely you did insert like:
>
> ```
> insert into mod_1237 (Collecteddepth) values (...)
> ```
>
> i.e. you didn't quote the column names. Hence the problem.
>
> In psql, you can do:
>
> ```
> \d mod_1237
> ```
>
> and you will see the columns are there.
>
> Best regards,
>
> depesz

In other words: If you double-quote names in table definitions, double-quote them wherever you refer to them too.

This is a FAQ; see:

- [PostgreSQL - query syntax without quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6304268/398670)
- [Omitting the double quote to do query on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6331504/398670)

and more.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the quotes as they are not needed.

```
CREATE TABLE mod_1237 (Collecteddepth float8 NOT NULL, Collectedtime float8 NOT NULL, CollectedDate Varchar(45) NOT NULL, Collectedpass float8 NOT NULL, Collectedmodtime float8 NOT NULL) WITH (OIDS = FALSE);
```

Comment: The quotes are necessary if some other software is going to be using `"Collecteddepth"` as a column name.

Comment: I can't take out the quotes because the letter case is required. The example above was just an example, but it was giving me the same problem as the table that I was actually trying to create. Any other ideas?